# Need to change the file path from on premise to sharepoint in power bi

Tags: powerbi

In this scenario, I am using on premise data source like excel file in power bi. Here I have made some ETL process and Calculations as well. Now the problem is, my client want me to do migrate all on premise data sources into sharepoint. For that, If I change the file path in power bi, can I have all the changes I made earlier?

Comment: Aditionally, you can ask at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/, a SE site dedicated to SharePoint only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change any transfomations if you read Excel via the web connector. However, if you're using the SharePoint Folder connector (recommended), you'll probably have to add an additional another navigation step to access the sheets.